# ImGui How to close a window?

Tags: c++, imgui

I'm using glfw with glad and imgui to create a launcher for my game engine.
Currently this is the bit that does all of the imgui stuff:

```cpp
bool projects = true;
bool versions = false;

ImGui::Begin("Tabs", 0, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize);
        
if (ImGui::Button("Projects"))
{
    projects = true;
    versions = false;
}
if (ImGui::Button("Editor Versions"))
{
    projects = false;
    versions = true;
}

ImGui::End();

if (projects)
{
   ImGui::Begin("Projects", &projects, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize);

    ImGui::End(); 
}

if (versions)
{
    ImGui::Begin("Versions", &versions, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize);

    ImGui::End();
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that when you click Editor Versions, it closes Projects and opens Versions and the other way around for Projects

Comment: and .. it doesn't? what happens instead?

Comment: @Botje well there should be a difference in the name, they're at the same size and position as I modified imgui.ini, but when I click on the buttons it still says projects instead of versions.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, I defined the variables in the loop! So they just kept on resetting to their default values. All I had to do was move it out of the `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))` loop